# Discord.js bot won't recognize fetch as a function (using node-fetch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am using discordjs to build a bot and one slashcommand I want to use is a web scraping command to let users know about the latest releases on their favorite platform.
The issue at the moment is that I get an error code saying the function "fetch" doesn't exist after importing node-fetch.
It works as a script it self but not when used in the discord bot environment.

I would like to know if any of you ran into a similar issue and if so, what was the solution?

Thank you for your time.

```
const { load } = require("cheerio");
const { fetch } = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("questnew")
    .setDescription("Get Quest releases!"),

  async execute(interaction, client) {
    try {
      const siteUrl = "http://www.vrdb.app/";
      const response = await fetch(siteUrl);
      const body = await response.text();
      const games = [];
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      const elSelector = "#oculus-statistics > tbody > tr";
      $(elSelector).each((parentIdx, parentEl) => {
        if (parentIdx >= 0 && parentIdx <= 4) {
          $(parentEl)
            .children()
            .each((childIdx, childEl) => {
              if (childIdx === 0) {
                games.push($(childEl).text());
              }
            });
        }
      });
      await interaction.reply({
        content: "There was an error while executing this command!" + games,
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      await interaction.reply({
        content: "There was an error while executing this command!" + error,
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong syntax

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
```

Comment: solved my issue. thank you.
the cheerio declaration was also problematic. I changed it to 
``` const cheerio = require("cheerio");```